# How to create a custom quiz leaderboard in a discord channel using Quizcord bot?

Tags: discord, bots

Problem Statement:

I have a Discord tech channel, and I would like to conduct a quiz event that will begin today and conclude the day after tomorrow.

Current Solution:

I found the Quizcord bot (https://www.quizcord.com/), which is a dedicated bot for quizzes. It has an inbuilt leaderboard for all quiz sessions.

Expected Solution:

I need a custom leaderboard for a specific time period to announce the winner at the end of the event. It would also be great if there are similar bots that can accomplish this.

Comment: This is a forum for developers. You are looking for already done solutions. There are no implementation question just for finished solution. If you want to implement feel free to ask a question regarding an implementation error you are running into concretely because as it stands now it could start at how to write a basic hello world discord bot. It doesn`t even mention the language.

Comment: @TinNguyen QuizCord is a 3rd party bot for Discord. Im facing issue to integrate it with my discord channel for establishing a Quiz event. I don't think there is a need to specifically mention the language for this issue.